# How to put space between div in a bigger div?

Tags: html, css

I have a big `<div>` with 3 smaller `<div>` inside.
I want to put space between the 3 little `<div>` without defining the size of the big `<div>` or put `margin-top` to each little `<div>`.

Here is my CSS :

```css
table
{
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background: white;
}
.div_tableaux
{
    border: 10px solid red;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-arround;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: 10%;
    padding: 30px;
}
```

Do you know how to do that in CSS ?

[image]
Red = Big div; blue = little div

Comment: some code will help

Comment: I cant rly show you anything because its private information and its just the result how matter. maybe an image

Comment: you need to show a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: you can delete the sensitive info and add dummy info

Comment: @TheTinyCat html code can be viewed by doing CTRL + U (in firefox) - html/css/js aren't private files - can all be seen in browser (unless the js and css directories are forbidden)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs it can be an interne page, so it's not always true

Comment: @Edwin true - but my point was browser-side languages aren't as private, nor even sensitive (information wise - unless you're hardcoding everything) unless an extra steps were taken (like hosting it internally, or setting privileges on directories)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just put another div's between them and set height to them:

```css
.red {
    width: 300px;
    border: 3px solid red;
    padding: 20px;
}

.blue {
    width: 90%;
    border: 3px solid blue;
}

.empty {
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="red">
    <div class="blue">
        content
    </div>
    <div class="empty">
    </div>
    <div class="blue">
        content
    </div>
    <div class="empty">
    </div>
    <div class="blue">
        content
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats nor a bad idea. There is no CSS attribute which do that i think.

Answer (score 1):

Try using flex:

```css
.father {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background: #333;
  padding: 5% 0;
}

.child {
  width: 25%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ff6600;
}
```

```html
<div class="father">

  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thats particulary what i do not want to do :/ sry

Comment: @TheTinyCat, what do not you want to do?

Comment: Just realised you want to split them vertically... the descriptive image wasn't there when I began to answer...

Comment: This answer. A class for each div.

Comment: No problem L.paz